# Why The Identity Criterion holds only on an open interval?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

According to the book Advanced Calculus by P M Fitzpatrick -

[image]

It is not clear from the proof why the theorem holds for an open interval. Does it hold for intervals of the type $[a,b]$ and $[a,b)$ and $(a,b]$? and why?

Comment: Often, deriviates are defined under the assumption that the function is defined in an open neighbourhood of the point. To formulate the theorem for closed intervals, you need to decide on what $g'(a)$ should mean when $a$ is an endpoint of the interval.

Comment: What does the previous lemma state? Does the proof of the lemma require that the interval be open? In any case, I'm guessing the proof requires an open interval so that derivatives given by two sided limits are defined everywhere on the interval. Allowing one or both of the endpoints requires the consideration of one sided limits.

Comment: @SamM - Yes, I forgot considering the previous lemma!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that the theorem doesn't hold on these other interval types -- it's that it doesn't make a lot of sense to say that a function on $[a, b]$ (say) is differentiable at $a$. (You could define it using left and right-hand limits, if you wished, of course, but this is not so useful.)

If, as is often the case in practice, the functions extend to differentiable functions on an interval bigger than $[a, b]$, then in particular the theorem is true on $[a, b]$, of course.